# Is there any verb that means "pour water"?

Tags: word-request

I am wondering if there's a verb that means "pour water" such that I don't have to mention "water" and can just mention the thing I am pouring water onto as a direct object of the verb.

> I am __ the flowers.

Answer (score 8):

Actually, using *water* seems most natural to me. Were you aware of this usage? Or, is there a reason you are rejecting this?

> [water](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/water)
> verb
> to pour water on to plants or the soil that they are growing in:
> • I've asked my neighbor to water the plants while I'm away.
> (Cambridge Dictionary)

*Example*:

> I am **watering** the plants.

Comment: **Irrigating** is an alternative -  generally used for gardens, crops, sports fields, golf courses etc rather than a few flowers,

Comment: @RonaldSole, You should write 'irrigate' as an answer.

Comment: @Wistful Seriously?  Is your comment a joke?  *I am irrigate the flowers*?  The comment section is not for jokes.  You should **not** write that as the answer, Willgang.

Comment: @EllieK, Not *irrigating flowers* but *garden, crops* etc.

Answer (score 3):

**Irrigating** is an alternative - generally used for gardens, crops, sports fields, golf courses etc rather than a few flowers.

To **water** is generally taken to mean by hand, either with a hose or watering can.

To **irrigate** is generally understood to mean using an irrigation system of pipes, sprays, drips and the like.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/irrigate